# How do you list local profiles with boto3 from ~/.aws/.credentials and ~/.aws/.config files?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I would like to list all of my local profiles using boto3, as I think boto3 is not picking up my credentials correctly.

I have tried the following:

```
import boto3

boto3.Session.available_profiles
```

Which doesn't give me a list, but a property object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to use `awscli` instead of `boto3` to list your profiles.

```
aws configure list
```

This should output something like this:

```
   Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************ABCD      config_file    ~/.aws/config
secret_key     ****************ABCD      config_file    ~/.aws/config
    region                us-west-2              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

As for `boto3`, try this:

```
for profile in boto3.session.Session().available_profiles:
    print(profile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, its specific to a section of code that I'm running and I believe my aws cli is not using the same profiles as boto3 running it.

So I would like to add a boto3 snippet inside the code to find out what it is doing.